# Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_assoc() expects exactly 0 parameters

Tags: php, mysql

So im trying to create a dropdown menu that has all the users in the database that are verified and not admin(which are both columns in database) and take the users name from column "Owner" and put each one in dropdown menu. I get the error Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_assoc() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in /home/content/96/10688096/html/testserver/requestpage.php on line 47

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['admin']=='y') {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/request.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='CSS/requestpage.css'> 

<title> Admin Page </title>

</head>

<body>

<!-- Header Divs -->
<div id='header'>

<div id='title'> 
<!-- Header Text -->


 </div>
</div>

<div id='sidebar'>
<?php

$username = $_SESSION['id'];
$usernamelc = strtolower($username);
$userimage = "<img src='images/$usernamelc.png'> ";
$adminid = $_SESSION['recid'];

include('connection.php');

$sidebar = "<div id='sidebar'> <table id='admininfo'> <tr> <td colspan='2'> $userimage</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td colspan='2'> <span> Welcome, $username </span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> Admin: </td> <td> $username </td> </tr> 
<tr> <td> ID: </td> <td> $adminid </td> </tr> <tr> <td> Number of Users: </td> <td> {$users} </td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan='2'> <span> Emulator </span> </td> </tr>  
<select>";

$users = $db->query("SELECT Owner FROM users WHERE verified = 'y' AND admin ='n'");

while ($row = $users->fetch_array($users)) {
$sidebar .= "<option value='{$row['Owner']}'> </option>";

} 
$sidebar .= "</select> </td> </tr> </table> </div>";
echo $sidebar;

?>



</div>


<?php

}


?>
```

Comment: The error message appears to be quite clear to me...

Comment: First of all there's `fetch_assoc` used in presented code. Secondly, error is quite clear.

Comment: A few of issues: First, your code contains no call to `fetch_assoc()`. Second, the documentation for that function explains how to use it. Third, this question has been answered repeatedly, at length, on this site. Check the "Related" sidebar and/or search utility for a few dozen examples.

Comment: Well the answers in the question, it's saying that the $users variable in the line beginning the while loop shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 3):

Read your error.

`while ($row = $users->fetch_array($users)) {`

Needs to become

`while ($row = $users->fetch_array()) {`

Comment: yes, but the op's error says "fetch_assoc"... which doesn't appear anywhere in the code snippet.

Comment: fetch_assoc is fetch_array with MYSQLI_ASSOC parameter I believe